# Placing an ImageView over a transparent SurfaceView

Tags: android, surfaceview, transparent

I have a SurfaceView with a transparent background, on which i draw stuff, and on top of that i want an ImageView to be drawn.
In order for the SurfaceView to be transparent i have to set `surfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true)`, but the problem is that now, my surfaceview's canvas is drawn on top of the imageview,
which makes sense because of `setZOrderOnTop(true)`. 

My question is, is there a way to achieve what i want? a SurfaceView with transparent background and an ImageView on top of it?

Thanks, 
Vlad

Edit: Ok so this isn't possible. See fadden's answer below, or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=duefsFTJXzc&feature=feedwll&list=WL for deeper understanding.

Comment: why? why not to draw ypur image in SurfaceView?

Comment: I'm building a library, and the user passes me this ImageView, so i don't have the image itself anywhere.

Comment: cannot he pass a Bitmap or Drawable ?

Comment: Well, our whole design is based on working with normal views.. he might want to give me a TextView for all that i care..

Comment: you can have of course ImageView placed on top of SurfaceView: simple FrameLayout will do that but the overall performance may suffer

Comment: That's exactly what i'm doing.. but read my question again

Comment: do you have: FrameLayout fl = ...; fl.addView(surfaceView); fl.addView(imageView) ?

Comment: yup.. i know how to add 2 views into a frame layout.. that's not the issue here

Comment: Something doesn't make sense here.  If you want the SurfaceView's Surface to be below everything, why not leave it there?  Do you really want ImageView above SurfaceView Surface above other View elements?  If you need the Surface to appear between View elements in the Z-order, you'll need to switch to a TextureView (API 14+).  If you just want to clear a Canvas to be transparent, just `setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)` on the SurfaceView and clear the Canvas with `canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)`.

Comment: @fadden setting the format and clearing wouldn't work without setZOrderOnTop(true). "why not leave it there?", what do you mean exactly? And i know about TextureView, unfortunately, i have to support lower API's

Comment: Making the Surface contents transparent would be *unnecessary* since the Surface part would be at the bottom of the layer stack, so there'd be nothing behind it to peek through, but it would *work* just fine.  Can you update your question with a description of what all you're drawing?  You want an ImageView on top of the SurfaceView Surface, but it sounds like you need to have other things *behind* the Surface as well?  All View elements go on one layer, the SurfaceView Surface goes on a different layer, so the Surface can't go *between* View elements in the Z order.

Comment: The last part of your comment, should be an answer not a comment. It would get my +1. I do need other views to be behind the SurfaceView, if what you've described is correct, than i probably need to think of some other way of doing this. Thanks

Comment: Written up as an answer.  Added a potential solution.

Comment: Please, refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474845/using-a-viewpager-over-a-camerapreview) question that I did last year. Eventually, I found the solution. It might help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you want with a single `SurfaceView`.

All Views are composed onto a single layer.  The `SurfaceView` has two parts, the "View" part (which is just a transparent place-holder) and the "Surface" part.  The latter is a completely separate layer.

So you can put the "Surface" part above all other Views or below all other Views, but you can't put it in between.  A `TextureView` will do what you want, but you need to be using API 14+ for that.

You can, however, have more than one `SurfaceView`, and put the "Surface" layers at different Z-levels.  There are good reasons not to do this -- once you have more than N surfaces the system compositor may switch to a less-efficient operating mode -- but it's possible.  See the "Multi-surface test" in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that placing the ImageView inside a PopupWindow. It can come from an xml layout.

Example:

```
View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popuplayout, null);
PopupWindow myPopup = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
myPopup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
myPopup.showAtLocation(rootView, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT, 100, 100);
```

Where 100, 100 is your x, y position.